# How to remove SKNode after it leaves the scene in SpriteKit

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I am building a game in SpriteKit where a player is trying to avoid collision with objects. objects are being created every 3 to 5 seconds and i'm trying to figure out a way to remove from parent once it collides with the bottom of the screen but for some reason it goes to game over when it happens Please see code below in landscape.

```
import SpriteKit

class PlayScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {

enum ColliderType: UInt32 {

    case none = 0
    case player1 = 1
    case object = 2
    case border = 4
    case remove = 8
}

gameOver = false

let ground = SKNode()
    ground.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
    ground.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: CGSize(width: self.frame.size.width + 500, height: 1))
    ground.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false

    ground.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = ColliderType.remove.rawValue
    ground.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = ColliderType.object.rawValue
    ground.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = ColliderType.none.rawValue

character1.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = ColliderType.player1.rawValue
    character1.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = ColliderType.object.rawValue
    character1.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = ColliderType.object.rawValue | ColliderType.border.rawValue

object1.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = ColliderType.object.rawValue
        object1.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = ColliderType.player1.rawValue | ColliderType.remove.rawValue
        object1.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = ColliderType.player1.rawValue | ColliderType.border.rawValue | ColliderType.object.rawValue

if contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == ColliderType.object.rawValue || contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask == ColliderType.object.rawValue {

gameOver == true
}

if contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == ColliderType.remove.rawValue || contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask == ColliderType.remove.rawValue {


            object1.removeFromParent()
// it runs this code as well as code above collision object with object but i want contact remove with object
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to post your full code for this in the future, instead of some random bits thrown together.

Your collision code doesnt make much sense. It should look more like this where you check if player->object and object->remove or vice versa

```
func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {

    let firstBody: SKPhysicsBody
    let secondBody: SKPhysicsBody

    // This way you only need to do 1 if statement for each collision.
    if contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask < contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask {
        firstBody = contact.bodyA
        secondBody = contact.bodyB
    } else {
        firstBody = contact.bodyB
        secondBody = contact.bodyA
    }


    // Player hit Object or Object hit Player
    if (firstBody.categoryBitMask == ColliderType.player.rawValue) && (secondBody.categoryBitMask == ColliderType.object.rawValue) {

        gameOver == true
    }

    // Object hit Remove or Remove hit Object
    if (firstBody.categoryBitMask == ColliderType.object.rawValue) && (secondBody.categoryBitMask == ColliderType.remove.rawValue) {

        // Remove object
        firstBody.node?.removeFromParent()
    }
}
```

I suggest you read some more tutorials about sprite kit collision, there are plenty available, if this is confusing to you.

Hope this helps